# How to Change value of nested array objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object

I want to change the checked value base on the id kindly help me to solve this.I'll pass an id which have to match in each object in sub_cat and if any result found then change the check value

```
  "data": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "name": "Electrical Repair & installation",
                "parent_id": "0",
                "image": "assets/images/Group66.png",
                "checked": "false",
                "sub_cat": [
                    {
                        "id": "7",
                        "name": "Sockets",
                        "parent_id": "1",
                        "image": "assets/images/Group66.png",
                        "checked": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "8",
                        "name": "Fans",
                        "parent_id": "1",
                        "image": "assets/images/Group67.png",
                        "checked": "true"
                    }
                ]
            },
         
           
        ]
```

Comment: Please add your try. Also add expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourObject.data[0].find(item => item.id === id_your_looking_for).checked = "true"
```

Ofc, you can wrap it in function and add a check if item is found, but i'm leaving it up to you :)

Comment: there will multiple objects and multiple arrays in objects

Comment: also there are two checked keys i want to change of sub_cat array's

Comment: So you need to figure out a rule, which ID's are going to change and then apply my code to the ID's which are matching the rule.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you will be checking on based some id.  I have added one variable as `chkID` to check with `sub_cat` `parent_id`. you can check as per your requirement.

```
let chkID =1;
data.map(res => res.sub_cat.find((subItem) =>{ if(subItem.parent_id==chkID){
             subItem.checked = true;
             }}))
```